# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage

Tags: python, database, file-upload, hash-function

This is the first time that I ask for help, I'm new here and I have seen that you help people to solve their programming issues.

So I'm asking how can I solve this one:

```
app.config["FILE_UPLOADS"] = "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/SAM_APP/dataBase"  

@app.route('/data', methods=['get', 'post'])                           
def data():   

    if request.method == "POST":                                                                       

        if request.files:                                                                              
            files = request.files["file"]                                                              
            print(files)                                                                               
            files.save(os.path.join(app.config["FILE_UPLOADS"], files.filename))                       
            print("FILE HAS BEEN SAVED")                                                               
            fic = open(files, "r", encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') 
            content = fic.read().encode()                                                              
            obj_hash = hashlib.sha256()                                                                
            obj_hash.update(content)                                                                   
            message = obj_hash.hexdigest()                                                             
        return redirect(request.url)                                                                   

    return render_template("data.html", files = message)
```

I upload a file in my path and i want to apply a hash-function in order to have a 
signature ot the file that i want to store in a database. The template render return a message that contains the signature of the file, just to check if is working.

Unfortunately, in my web page i have this response :

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage
```

If anyone have a solution, I will be thankful.

Ps: Is for my school project, Thanks alot.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you have to use `files.filename` in `open(files.filename, ... )`